# How can I assign one of the built-in icons to a UIButton programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

In the storyboard of XCode 11.5 there are several icons in the "image" property of a UIButton. However, I can't find any references to these images in the documentation and when attempting to create a button programatically I can only find references to using images I put in the bundle myself. Is there a way of accessing these built-in images from the code? How?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [SFSysmbol](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) icons. If you're asking about an auto-complete in Xcode when adding images programmatically, there isn't one. But you can get the list of all the available SFSymbols from this [app](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/). And you can use `UIImage(systemName:)` initializer to access the available icons.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To access system icons:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "wrench")
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, simple and elegant. Cheers!

Comment: `UIImage(systemName:)` Applies only for iOS 13+.